# Comparing defined and undefined variables

Tags: c, tree, null, boolean, binary-tree

I made a basic Tree struct as follows

```
typedef struct Tree {
    int val;
    struct Tree *left, *right;
}Tree;
```

I created two trees, one with a val of 16, and the other with no value. Not NULL, just simply no value. (The tree itself is NULL but the value is not)

When i compared the two values, i noticed that whether i put > or <, it would always evaluate to false.

Will this be the case all the time? Because if so that is pretty convenient. Is there any case where this would not work?

Comment: You've created undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is fun because no matter what happens, it's still "following the rules" of undefined behavior. Sometimes it might do one thing, sometimes it might do another thing, and sometimes it might turn off the sun.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi: Given the information in the question, we can only conclude the value of the object is indeterminate, not that the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @eric given the lack of information in the post we can't conclude anything. Notice that < with pointers not in the same array has undefined behaviour

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The statement that the object was given no value means it was not initialized and therefore has an indeterminate value.

Comment: @eric you assume that OP knows the difference between default-initialization and no initialization but does not know if indeterminate values can be safely compared...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: What I assume is the statements written in the question are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do not initialize an object, its initial value is *indeterminate* (C 2018 6.2.4). This means not only is its value not controlled (no deterministic setting of the value has been made by the C source code) but that is value is not even fixed (when used more than once, it may behave as if it has a different value each time). In addition, depending on circumstances, use of an uninitialized object may also have behavior that is not defined by the C standard—not only might its value be anything at all, but attempting to use the value may cause the program to crash or misbehave in other ways.

When the value of an uninitialized object is used (and is merely indeterminate, not undefined), the compiler is free to behave as if it has any value. As part of optimization, the compiler may therefore omit any actual testing of the value and generate code that branches as if the test were true or false, as the compiler happens to choose. What code the compiler generates will effectively be happenstance and not controllable by you. You cannot rely on a test always evaluating to false.

Always initialize your objects.

Comment: Or because op was not asked to produce a mre it might be that the other was initialized and hence null

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The question states, and emphasizes, that the object was given no value. If it was given no value, it was not initialized—initialization, whether implicit or explicit, gives the object a value.